# button click event fires multiple times inside of a Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, dom-events

I have a bug (or feature) whereby any button that is inside a Bootstrap 3 modal will fire the click event several times. Besides going "old-school" and calling a script from an HTML button directly (which always works), is there a workaround for this?

```
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <span id="spanSendReport">
                            <button type="button" id="btnSendReport" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Send Report</button></span>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
```

And the jquery

```
$("#btnSendReport").click(function (e) {
... my code
});
```

Using Bootstrap v3.4.1 and jQuery v3.3.1

Never ran into this before (except with things posting back, but there are no postbacks of any kind happening - checked in the browser and in debugger).
There is only 1 button in the DOM with the Id (first thing I checked), but it fires the click event 4 times, every time!
Any ideas?

NOTE: I forgot to mention, the modal is opened from another modal. Maybe that has something to do with it.

The complete code inside the click event function (just in case it has something to do with it):

```
$("#btnSendReport").click(function (e) {
        var parElem = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        var listID = parElem.find("#hidLID").val();
        var problemTypes = $.map(parElem.find('option:selected'), function (e) { return e.value; }).join(',');
        var problemTypeOther = parElem.find("#txtProblemTypeOther").val();

        var obj = {};
        obj.lid = listID;
        obj.ProblemTypes = problemTypes;
        obj.ProblemTypeOther = problemTypeOther;

        try {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../../api/reportdiscrepancy/",
                data: obj,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = data;
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does "my code" do? Also, are there any other elements on the page with the same id `btnSendReport`?

Comment: didn't think it was relevant, but I'll post the "my code" - it just makes an ajax call is all.  There is only 1 element with the ID of `btnSendReport`

Comment: Is your click handler being added inside a loop, potentially one iterating 4 times?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem, not just a few snippets of code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem and the answer to many issues I've been running into before and the culprit is `function pageLoad()` which is what older ASP.Net webforms uses for client side actions.
I removed the '#btnSendReport' click to OUTSIDE of the pageLoad() function and it's only firing once now.

It looks like any MS-AJAX accumulates ALL event bindings (not actually firing them) within an UpdatePanel, then a final call to a click event (or whatever) will fire x number of times.

I was clued in as I made 3 changes to get to the modal and the last thing I did was click on the button (so it fired 4 times).
I believe it may have to do with the default setting of the UpdatePanel with ChildrenAsTriggers=True (unfortunately, I have to leave that on as other functionality breaks if set to false).

Comment: If you are using ASP.net, you should edit your original question to add that tag.

Comment: yes, won't make that mistake anymore - my bad.